# Loading css (stylesheet) ONLY for IE11

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, internet-explorer-11, conditional-comments

I want to load a `css` file only for IE11 browser. How can I do it?

I understand that I can use [`conditional comments`](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) to load stylesheet's for IE <=9. But not for IE 10 & 11.

I could Google and find an alternative as below :

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
/* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

But, it loads for both IE10 and IE11 browsers. I want to load stylesheet **only** for IE11. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: have a look to this stack-overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/a/27315792/1306308

Comment: Thanks Arpit, the link is indeed good. I could atleast use Modernizr and get my task done. Lets see. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it's only IE11

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none)
 {
 .foo { color: green } /* IE10 */
 *::-ms-backdrop, .foo { color: red } /* IE11 */
 }
```

If you're targeting IE 9, 10, 11 you can try

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) { 
    /* Enter CSS here */
}
```

If it's for IE10+

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* IE10+ specific styles go here */  
}
```

Also, a [google search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20541859/4404971) came up with this

```
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .ie11up { property:value; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this using jquery you can can add class to body and add your css as normally it will take class only when it ie 11

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 11) {
 $("body").addClass("ie10");
}
```