# CSS Animation Not Working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header animation where it starts out at 5% width and increases to 100% width. I also need it to move from left: 45%; to left: 0%; I've been able to accomplish exactly what I need in Chrome and FireFox, but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

Here's my CSS:

```
@keyframes header-build {
    from {width: 5%;}
    to {width: 100%;}
    from {left: 45%;}
    to {left: 0%;}
}

 header{
    width: 5%;
    min-width: 5%;
    left: 45%;
 }

.action{
    animation-name: header-build;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-delay: 1s;

    -webkit-animation-name: header-build;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;


    -moz-animation-name: header-build;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;

    -o-animation-name: header-build;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

The class "action" is added to the header on page load via js.

This works in all browsers except for IE, but even in IE it moves from 45% to 0%, the width just doesn't change.

Is there a prefix I'm missing or an alternate way of animating the width in Internet Explorer?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm using Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: I'm using IE version 11

Comment: [Is this the animation that you want?](http://jsbin.com/hiyamu/1/edit?html,css,output) Place both the properties in a single `from` and `to`.

Comment: as per my experience it should work on IE 10 and above, please see this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the animation

```
@keyframes header-build {
    from {width: 5%;}
    to {width: 100%;}
    from {left: 45%;}
    to {left: 0%;}
}
```

with

```
@keyframes header-build { 
    from {width: 5%;left: 45%;}
    to {left: 0%;width: 100%;}
}
```

As `from` is equivalent to `0%` and `to` to `100%`, you should declare 1 time each and group your properties that should be animated in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is with your `keyframe` declaration, as you cannot declare `to` and `from` multiple times in your keyframes.

Instead, place all your `to` properties in a single `{}`, separated by a semicolon, (as you would with 'normal' CSS):

```
@keyframes header-build {
    from {
           width: 5%;
           left: 45%;
         }
    to   {
           width: 100%;
           left: 0%;
         }
```

If you needed 'extra' breakpoints/ positions as well, rather than using `from` and `to`, you would use `0%` and `100%`, with possibly a `50%`, for example.

---

*As a side note*

Your unprefixed version of your animation **should always** be placed **after** the prefixed versions, and not before.