# Angular 2 money number space after 3 zeros

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization

for example I have number : 30000 and I want to display it like this : 30 000. What should I use for it ?

More examples : 300000 -> 300 000,

3000000 -> 3000 000.

And not it's not about dots or comas, I want to recognize how many numbers there are and put space between numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222018/how-to-format-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: nah its not, there about . and ,

Comment: There are plenty of examples and solutions here on SO.

Comment: If you knew you wouldnt comment that. No need of those non sence comments here.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843217/adding-a-space-to-a-phone-number-with-just-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

consider using a pipe that takes the number, convert it to a string and format it as you like.. you could add a currency two.

example:(more of a point illustration than a working code.. can't test at the moment)

```
//convert the string to an array
var arr = str.split("");
//back to string with added spaces
let string = "";
let count = 0;
for(i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
 if(count<3){
  string =  arr[i] + string;
  count = count+1;
 }
 else{
  string = " " + string;
  count=0;
  i=i+1;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example please.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag example is not necessary, because no code was given. The question was what to use for it. And a pipe is the best solution

Comment: An example is not necessary ofc - but for the sake of a good community write 2 lines of code if you know how it works. This will improve the answer itself a lot. I previously gave this answer a upvote. Nevertheless I can ask for an example

Answer (score 1):

Either by using javascript as following:

```js
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
   var parts = x.toString().split(".");
   parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
   return parts.join(".");
}
var num = numberWithSpaces(123456789);
console.log(num);
```

This will output `123 456 789`

Edit:

Typescript:

```js
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
  let parts = x.toString().split('.');
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ');
  return parts.join('.');
}
let num = this.numberWithSpaces(123456789);
console.log(num);
```

add into your typescript file (.ts) which are related to your html which contain your `<h2>item.price</h2>` replace `num` with your `item.price` value.

Or using [pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe).

You could see example on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcyuxx)**

Just simply call by: `element.price = format.formatCurrency(element.price);`

Once you've define the helper. For your  usage you could define by:
`<h2 *ngFor="let item of item">{{ item.price }}</h2>`

Comment: how to use this function if I have <h2>{{item.price}}</h2>

Comment: updated my answer. you need to add into your ts to define your price =  num.

Answer (score 1):

Make you own custom pipe:
https://toddmotto.com/angular-pipes-custom-pipes

In the transform function, convert it to a string like so:
[Add commas or spaces to group every three digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784894/add-commas-or-spaces-to-group-every-three-digits)

Answer (score 0):

Extremely simple way to do this:

```
function formatNumber(num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```