# Specify CSS properties for the IE only in the CSS file

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Actually I need to specify this property

```
margin-left:-20px;
```

only for the IE-11 and the rest of the properties for all browsers in CSS file

```
.navigator li a span {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    }
```

Is there a way to do that, as I tried many solutions and didn't work
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you only need `margin-left` for IE? If this is due to a display quirk in IE there may be a better way of handling the issue without resorting to browser sniffing.

Comment: Microsoft removed browser specific css from recent browsers, although you can do it with a hack (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11) not recommended though! You should try and fix the underlying issue, since ie11 is relatively modern, and should adhere to standards.

Comment: Does your code work on IE10 or others have checked that .?

Comment: @NickR
hack resolved the issue !<br/> but the problem is I don't know why that strange behavior happened in IE only.

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara
Actually I am not interested in IE-10. I am focusing on IE-11

Comment: @Yasmin, if you provide a full reproducible example we should be able to give you a non-hacky solution and explain what the problem is.

Comment: @Yasmin Check if your markup is valid - [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote is very simple and only supported by IE 11+

```html
<style type="text/css">
  _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .msie11 { color: blue; }
</style>

// or you can try this

<style>
  @media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none)
    {         
      *::-ms-backdrop, .foo { color: red } /* IE11 */
    }
</style>
```

and of course the div...

```html
<div class="msie11">
    This is an Internet Explorer 11 and greater CSS Hack
<div>
```

So the text shows up in blue with internet explorer 11 and greater. Have fun with it.

for more reference you can look around with given link

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11)**

Comment: @Yasmin honored to help you if you find answer help full you can just accept as answer  or you can upvote it

Comment: @Yasmin  and you should accept any of following answers so that this case can be closed

Comment: I tried the second solution(*::-ms-backdrop) and it worked fine with me. Thank you so much for the help. I am sorry for the delay in accepting the answer. I thought that I upgraded and accepted the answer.

Comment: @Yasmin no problem at all,i honored to help you.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me so much especially since IE 10 and up DO NOT support conditional comments at all. Your solution helped me fix my own site in modern IE browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem could be solved in some other way than browser-conditional styles, please try that first, but in any case:

**For IE 10 and 11, you can use this:**

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
/* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

Note though, that it will recognize both IE 10 and 11.

source: https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/04/target-internet-explorer-10-11-css/

You may also want to take a look at this:

http://marxo.me/target-ie-in-css/

---

**For IE 9 and lower, you can use this:**

You create a separate stylesheet for that, and then you use this to include that in your HTML.

source: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

For example, if you wanted to target IE 7, you would do this. You can just change the version number to what you will.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

And then you can also target lower or higher versions than a specific version:

Lower than IE 8 and IE 8:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Higher than IE 8:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Note that you can use `lt`, `lte`, `gt` or `gte`.

Comment: From the very article that you linked to: _“Note that IE 10 and up DO NOT support conditional comments at all.”_

Comment: @CBroe Too bad I just realized that myself as well. So, this does not apply. I have added a solution for IE 10 and 11 as well, though it recognizes both of them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and I'll try this solution as well.