# conditional css statements for Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am developing a website that has a div with a background image that is has the css

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

This looks good in all browsers MINUS internet explorer. Implementing smooth scrolling via javascript isn't an option.

So I found a plugin that allows me to determine when IE 10 and 11 is being used. 
https://github.com/stowball/Layout-Engine

I tested this with the following code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (layoutEngine.vendor === 'ie' && layoutEngine.version === 11) {
            alert("using IE 11");
        }
    </script>
```

And got the following [image: IE Image]

So I know this is working. So I used this same concept to use Jquery to add an additional class.

CSS

```
  .grouppic{
      background-attachment:fixed;
  }

  .grouppicIEVersion{
      background-attachment:inherit !important;
  }
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (layoutEngine.vendor === 'ie' && layoutEngine.version === 11) {
        $('#groupPicture').addClass("grouppicIEVersion");
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <div class="w-section grouppic " id="groupPicture">
    <div class="w-container">
    </div>
   </div>
```

But this doesn't work. The class doesn't get added in internet explorer. I'm not sure if this is a jquery error or something with the plugin I'm using. Some help would be great.

Comment: Well are you calling it before the elements are added to the page? It is like someone calling your name before you show up.

Comment: oh wow. did not even consider that. Hold on.

Comment: generally better to use feature detection instead of checking browser and version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Ivanka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32205159/370103) has stated this needs to be wrapped in a document ready function or else the DOM may not have loaded and therefore the `#groupPicture` element may not exist yet.

A further point I would make is to attach a class to the `body` and use this in your CSS instead. This means you attach the class once and then can apply browser overrides using CSS only from then on.

For example:

```
$(function(){
   if (layoutEngine.vendor === 'ie' && layoutEngine.version === 11) {
      $("body").addClass("msie11");
   }
});
```

Then the CSS can just be:

```
.grouppic{
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

.msie11 .grouppic{
    background-attachment:inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Wow, haven't though of this. Applying a class on the whole body is way more easier and less of a pain when writing CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

but you can easily find out using the css hack's then why to use the other pluggin to find out that

```html
<style>
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none)
     {
     .grouppicIEVersion{ background-attachment:inherit !important;  } /* IE10 */
     *::-ms-backdrop, .grouppicIEVersion{background-attachment:inherit !important;
  } /* IE11 */
     }
  </style>
```

here the reference link you can check out
**[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11)**

Comment: @onTheInternet please check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `$.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (layoutEngine.vendor === 'ie' && layoutEngine.version === 11) {
        $('#groupPicture').addClass("grouppicIEVersion");
    }
});
```

Probably when you want to add this class, the element `#groupPicture` is not available in the DOM yet.

Also check for errors in your console.