# How to specify IE 11 for bottom element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

How do I specify IE 11 in my css? I have other IE accounted for as follows.

```
#teleport {

bottom: -230px;

bottom: -280px\9; /* IE 8 and below */

*bottom: -280px; /* IE 7 and below */

_bottom: -280px; /* IE 6 */

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11 Btw, why you should target IE11 (just curiosity)? Even IE 11 can't handle your CSS properly?

Comment: Because my `<div>` is out of position in IE10 and IE11. Other browsers are fine.

Comment: Did you try using padding or margin instead of negative bottom ? Maybe it's not IE11's fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
    _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .ie11up, #teleport { bottom: -280px; }

     @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   .ie10up, #teleport{bottom: -280px; }
}
```

Problem solved.