# Is there a way to hide elements in IE11 and lower, but keep them in Edge?

Tags: css

I am looking for a way to hide div in IE11 and lower, but still have it display in Edge and other browsers.

Is it best to hide elements like this using Javascript?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

Comment: Yes, found out type and (if you want) version of browser with JS and hide element with it. CSS can not help you here much (I believe)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting IE11 using CSS Capability/Feature Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-capability-feature-detection)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11

Answer (score 1):

http://browserhacks.com/

IE8-11:

```
@media screen\0 {
  body { display: none };
}
```

IE <= 8:

```
@media \0screen\,screen\9 { body { display: none } }
```

[Detecting IE11 using CSS Capability/Feature Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-capability-feature-detection)
*@JanKyuPeblik*:

> This works because IE11 doesn't actually even support `@supports`, and [all other relevant browser/version combinations](http://caniuse.com/#search=%40supports) do.

```
body { display:none }
/**/@supports not (old: ie) {
body { display:unset }
/**/}
```