# css filter not applying in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, cross-browser, icons

To Apply color for bootstrap 2.3.2 Icons, I am using filter property in CSS.
This works good in all browsers except IE11.

```
.apply-color {
    filter: opacity(0.5) drop-shadow(0 0 0 blue);
}
```

How can we achieve this for IE.

Answer (score 1):

IE 11 DOES NOT support `filter` at all: https://caniuse.com/?search=filter.

There are different JS polyfils for filter techniques like 'grayscale' but I am not sure if there is one for you special settings which are more simple.

Thinking forward: as you really 'only' use `opacity` and `drop-shadow` you don't need `filter` in that case ...

IE11 supports:

- `opacity`
- `box-shadow`

... so you could achieve your styling without filters. And if you really need to provide  support for eight years old and long outdated (nearly) not used IE11: just wrap the special settings for IE11 traditional to a separate IE11 stylesheet and include it to your html (**see update below**):

```
<!--[if IE 11]>
  <link href="ie11.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

---

**UPDATE**

According to the comment from Rich DeBourke below: **IE11 does not support conditional comments**. Here are additional links to that point (really a long time ago):

Information about conditional comments:
https://www.sitepoint.com/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/

Information about writing special CSS for old IE versions including IE11:
[How to write a CSS hack for IE 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11)
https://paper-leaf.com/insights/targeting-ie-10-11-browsers-css/

Comment: IE 10 & 11 do not support conditional comments (per this article on [Sitepoint.com](https://www.sitepoint.com/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/)). IE 9 and up do support [opacity](https://caniuse.com/css-opacity) and [box-shadow](https://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow) per CanIUse.com. If you think you might be getting users running old version of IE, then you can do as Brebber said and use a condition stylesheet for old versions of Internet Explorer via `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`.

Comment: @RichDeBourke: Thx for correction ... that techniques are really a long time back.