# Visual bug in IE 11/Edge with border-radius and image-background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I want to styling a `select` item. I use an arrow image as background and hide the default down arrow using css.

You can see the effect here. Everything go right with Chrome and Firefox. However IE11 and Edge have a visual bug. The lower `select` item has a white margin between image background and border.

To reproduce the problem, you can apply css combination with `border-radius`, `image-background` and `border`.

How can I fix this problem?

It is not about blur during image resize. The image background is in actual size.

https://jsfiddle.net/k3kxfstv/3/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723057/ie11-making-background-image-text-blurry

Comment: @LaljiTadhani even I use `linear-gradient` the problem still exist